# Angular JS state provider login and registration handling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes

I am new to angular js, and I am creating admin panel with angular js but I have issue as follows:

```
$stateProvider
                .state('app', {
                    url: '',
                    templateUrl: 'menu/menu.html',
                    controller: 'menuCntrl',
                    abstract: true,
                    authenticate: true
                })
                .state('dashboard', {
                    url: "/",
                    templateUrl: 'dashboard/dashboard.html',
                    controller: 'DashboardCtrl',
                    parent: "app",
                    authenticate: true


                })
                .state('login', {
                    url: "/login",
                    templateUrl: 'dashboard/test.html',
                    controller: 'LoginCtrl',
                    authenticate: false
                })
            $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

this is my current routing now my issue is I need to handle login and registration with it. as like if user is logged in then only user can see the dashboard but I can't understand how to handle it.

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            if (toState.authenticate ) {
                $state.go("/");
                event.preventDefault();
            }else{
                $state.go("/login");
            }
        })
```

this is also I have tried but not worked and also I need to handle registration as well...

can anyone help to figure out what will be best method to handle login and registration before user will redirect to dashboard.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store some value in **localstorage or cookies or session** to save user is login or not.

Create a function to check user is loged in or not.

In menu controller check if user is login then fine other wise redirect on login page.

Same in your app config.
if user is login then use this:

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
```

other wise if user is not login then use this:

```
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
```